# How to fill the value in build.gradle in Android studio?

Tags: android

There are lines in build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.21'
    }
```

However, when building the project, the error notes say,
           "Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.21."

So how to find the gradle number that installed in my Android Studio?

Source code is from the official training: [Developer site](http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/DisplayingBitmaps.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradle plugin version is incorrect. Try this:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (+) sign for the latest version:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
```